# App Deployment: Keep the existing data in internal list of an SharePoint APP

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app

In my SharePoint hosted APP, I use 2 internal lists. They are managed using REST API calls.
It works great however I have a problem while uploading a new version on my site. 
The data in internal lists are deleted.

How can I deploy a new version of an application without loosing the data in internal lists?

Comment: Are you increment app version in Visual Studio (ex. from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1) and using **Upgrade** mechanize?

Comment: What do you mean with "Upgrade mechanize"?

Comment: Firstly, you should set up [app catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123530.aspx). Upload your app with version 1.0.0.0. Install app to to the desired web. After some code modification increment your version to 1.0.0.1 and upload again your app to catalog. Upgrade your installed app. [More details about updating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx).